# Doubts with the conversion that pandoc does

Tags: symbols, pandoc

I have migrated a large document from InDesing to `.html` and then passed that document to `.tex` using pandoc.

The conversion is almost perfect, I just have to correct a few things manually.

In the content I have two doubts:

1. In the case of `...` pandoc does this conversion: `\ldots{}`
2. And when there is content with `[` and with `]` pandoc places it like this: `{[}Lorem ipsum{]}`

Since I am correcting all the content and this I can easily fix with find / replace I want to know **if there are any specific rules in LaTeX regarding (1) and (2)**.

With respect to what is exposed in (1), I suppose that the correct way is as pandoc puts it, because in a manual test, if I do not put `{}` at the end, it does not respect the white space that would follow, then `Lorem\ldots ipsum` will print: `Lorem...ipsum`.

With respect to what is exposed in (2), I do not see any difference.

Comment: with (2) pandoc is probably trying to avoid that the brackets are interpreted as starting or ending an optional arguments of something, e.g. this here would simply error `abc \\ [lorem] `

Comment: @UlrikeFischer In case (2) there would be no problem then in replacing `{[}` by `[` and `{]}` by `]`, verifying that the error you mention does not occur?

Comment: You can replace every of these bracket if you are sure that no commands will confuse them with optional arguments delimiters.